# Why do i need same using twice in razor?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have a index.razor file and a index.razor.cs file.

index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp8.Data

<h3>Index</h3>
<ComponentX></ComponentX>
```

index.razor.cs

```
//same story having the using outside of the namespace
//using BlazorApp8.Data; 
namespace BlazorApp8.Pages
{
    using Data;

    public partial class Index
    {
        public ComponentX ComponentX { get; set; } = new ();
    }
}
```

This is just a sample. But i have a real case that needs the using in both parts.

When I remove one of the usings in the razor part it wont work anymore. Why do I need the using two times when its a partial class?

Comment: Plain and simple, because there may be things you need in the backend file that you won't need in the razor page. Remember that using statements are just simply a shorthand for spelling out the entire namespace for imported types. Theoretically you can do all of your work without *any* using imports....just means you have to fully write out the name of objects. Ex. `Console.WriteLine()` must be `System.Console.WriteLine()` for the entire class

Comment: Also, worth noting that the compiler throws our your using directives and will fully write in the entire namespace nomenclature on its own in the intermediate language. Its purely something for your own coding workflows. To cover all bases, I should mention that `using() {}` blocks are different, as they will automatically dispose of used objects that inherit from `IDisposable`. In that case, the compiler will handle writing in the `.Dispose()` method when it is ready to collect. It compiles down to try-catch-finally blocks where the finally will contain the disposal

Comment: `public ComponentX ComponentX { get; set; } = new ();` is weird, that is not going to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a `using <namespace>` directive applies to the *compilation unit* it is in. And that means the file.

The compiler merges the partial class definitions into one class but they remain in separate compilation units.

Nothing specific to Blazor, this is basis C#.

Comment: The Razor compiler, which runs before the main compiler, compiles the `Index.razor` file into a C# partial file.  The main compiler then merges the files.